# React-native Update content of side-menu

Tags: react-native

I used react-native-navigation drawer. I have a sidemenu that displays the name of the logged-in user. Now I want this name changed whenever the user updates his profile. I really dont know how to go about this. On the profile page I imported the Sidemenu like below

```
import SideMenu from './SideMenu';
```

and I did

```
new SideMenu().updateState("new name");
```

UpdateState(name) is a method in sideMenu that sets state that displays name. Name is not getting changed

Comment: You could make use of redux for your use-case.

Comment: Any luck till now ?